# How to make UIButton Exactly round

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make UIButton exactly round,this code is creating oval button

```
  _img.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
  _img.layer.cornerRadius = 100;
  _img.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
  _img.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  _img.layer.borderWidth=.5f;
```

Please help[image]

Comment: Is the radius >= half the height? need a bit more information before answering.

Comment: yes  radius >= half the height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the property cornerRadius should be the half of the width / height (height and width should be the same)

use this code for a button exactly round:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

button.frame = CGRectMake(135.0, 70.0, 40.0, 40.0); //width and height should be same value

button.clipsToBounds = YES;

button.layer.cornerRadius = 20; //half of the width

button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

button.layer.borderWidth= 2.0f;

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why did you assign border width twice? Though it has nothing to do with round button but it's a bad coding example. Anyway, make sure that **_img** width and height are both equal to 200 if you want a rounded button with 100 corner radius. e.g.

```
_img.frame = CGRectMake(/* x origin of the button*/, /*y origin of the button*/, 200, 200);
_img.layer.cornerRadius = 100;
_img.layer.clipsToBounds = YES;
_img.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
_img.layer.borderWidth=.5f;// or 2.0f
```

hope this will make your button, or whatever _img is, rounded.

Answer (score 0):

First make img width and height same
Img.clipstobounds=YES;
And then make layer.cornertadius equal to width/2 of img